# Rails: Jwplayer 7 with cloudfront doesn't work on ios devices because of flash player

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

So I have integrated [jwplayer](https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/) v7 on my rails application, I use Jwplayer to stream videos hosted on [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/cloudfront/) s3 and distributed through cloudfront. The videos are rendering super smoothly on desktop. But there is an error on mobile devises. This is a known issues because flash is not supported on mobile devices, I know. But I can't figure out how to allow html5 play on mobile devices. I followed this [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html):  I tried to implement an html fallback following this [tutorial](http://www.miracletutorials.com/embed-streaming-video-audio-with-html5-fallback/), but this did not work..

Here is the code I use to render the videos:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/jwplayer.js'></script>
```

```
<script>jwplayer.key="xxxxx==";</script>

<div id="my-video-3"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer("my-video-3").setup({
     file: "rtmp://s2u8jn9qmths7o.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/aldo2.mp4",
     primary: "flash"
   });
</script>
```

Can someone put me on tracks to switch to html on mobile devices ?

Comment: I don't think you can play rtmp without flash.  Have you looked into transcoding the video into hls and using a download distribution?

Comment: @imperalix You are right. rtmp doesn't support html5 it's readble in flash player only, this is why it is not working on mobile devices.  But in this case what would be an alternative ?

Comment: The most common alternative is HLS - it's supported natively in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

JW Player is "mobile ready" video player and it should work fine on mobile devices. Try to remove `primary: "flash"` option from your setup:

```
jwplayer("my-video-3").setup({
    file: "rtmp://s2u8jn9qmths7o.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/aldo2.mp4"
});
```

Comment: Ok I may said it the wrong way. The problem is not the player, it's that I am using rtmp wich is only supported by flash player.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, you answered your question then. Convert it to some supported encoding.

Comment: BTW, rtmp was a "real time" streaming format, right. Not encoding. Since your server already supports streaming, JWPlayer also [supports it by default](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430349-about-rtmp-streaming). So, go ahead and remove that "flash" option.